# Check if the same number is randomized twice in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've made a quote generator, but often times, because there are only a few quotes, same quote shows up twice in a row. How would I check and avoid this issue?

```
    randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * quotes.length));
    randomQuote = quotes[randomNum];
    randomAuthor = author[randomNum];

    $("#quote").text(randomQuote);
    $("#author").text(randomAuthor);
}

$("#newQuote").on('click', function() {
    getQuote();
});
```

Full [code](https://codepen.io/Kestvir/pen/peqjZZ).

Comment: Just remember the last quote and compare?

Comment: Make an array of quotes and shuffle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check if the new random quote is equal to previous quote and change if it is.

replace `randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*quotes.length))` with

```
while(randomQuote === quotes[randomNum])
        randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*quotes.length));
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution I had while loop in mind too, but I thought that it wouldn't work.Here is why I thought so. If the new random quote is the same as the previous, the code inside the while loop will change it, but why does code still work if the new random quote is different than the previous one, shouldn't it only work, if it is the same?

Comment: check the code properly, code inside the loop is not changing randomQuote, it is only changing randomNum

Comment: Also, forgot to ask, how does the fuction execute in the first place, if the randomNum only gets a value, when the condition inside the while loop is true ? Sorry if the questions are obvious, I'm not very good with while loops

Comment: randomQuote gets updated after while loop, `randomQuote = quotes[randomNum]`